# Java date format conversion

Tags: java, date-conversion

date from database

```
2013-10-26T10:31:20GMT+05:30
```

UI Date

```
 Mon Feb 10 00:00:00 GMT+05:30 2014
```

need to convert according to Database Date

Comment: suggest me any solution for that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try this

```
Date dNow = new Date( );
      SimpleDateFormat ft = 
      new SimpleDateFormat ("E yyyy.MM.dd 'at' hh:mm:ss a zzz");

ft.format(dNow);
```

Note: give your format to SimpleDateFormat ,it will then format as shown above.

Comment: your result is Fri 2014.10.10 at 12:00:00 AM GMT+05:30   but i need    2013-10-26T10:31:20GMT+05:30  very close

Comment: @krishan i saw your question then your answers but could not understand your requirement.Be clear what you need.this answer is fine

Comment: Try this new SimpleDateFormat ("yyyy.MM.dd 'T' hh:mm:ss a zzz");

Answer (score 0):

Use following code

```
    // This is how to get today's date in Java
    Date today = new Date();// use your date here
   //SimpleDateFormat example - Date with timezone information
    SimpleDateFormat DATE_FORMAT = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm  'GMT'Z '('z')'");
    String date = DATE_FORMAT.format(today);
    System.out.println("Today in yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm  'GMT'Z '('z')' : " + date);
```

Comment: your result is  10-05-15:00:00:00 +0530 but i need 2013-10-26T10:31:20GMT+05:30

Comment: I have changed the date pattern try now